# Web Framework that can be developed in both Windows and Linux environments

Tags: java, asp.net, python, ruby, apache

I am not intending to start a flamewar here, I just want to know your opinions about this.

I have background in HTML/CSS/JavaScript, procedural PHP and ASP.NET Razor WebPages.

The reason I am asking for your suggestions is that I want to learn other web framework that I can develop in both Windows and Linux. The web application will be deployed in Linux, preferably using the Apache Web Server.

I am no expert in programming, the web apps I developed (blogs and hello worlds) are just companions for my learning in server side programming.

Can you suggest web frameworks that I can use for more serious web programming and has XAMPP like package that I can use out of the box?

**Please no PHP related stuffs**.

Thank you for your responses!

Comment: And why no PHP? At first glance a php framework seems to be what you are looking for :? Also, you don't tell us which language you prefer instead of php. There are usually many frameworks for each language and there are many languages...

Comment: I am looking for Java, Python and Ruby, but I have no idea how to setup this technologies. The reason I used PHP and ASP.NET before is that I can already use it out of the box.

Comment: If I can only deploy ASP.NET WebPages in Linux, I will stick to it. But I can't find a detailed guide on how to do it.

Comment: Java, Python and Ruby can all be easily deployed on both Windows and Linux, and offer a wide range of web development frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the programming language that you would like to try, my suggestion is:

- python - [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)
- ruby - [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)
- java - [Play](http://www.playframework.org)

There are surely other very good frameworks out there, for any of these languages, but these are the ones I find to provide the best documentation, in quality and amount. You can easily find quickstart/overview tutorials on their websites.

Comment: I ended up choosing Django, but learnig first Python before heading to the Django framework.

Comment: Btw, for learning python, be sure to check Mark Pilgrim's [DiveIntoPython](http://www.diveintopython.net/). It's available for free in the previous link but it's also available [in print](http://www.amazon.com/Dive-Into-Python-Mark-Pilgrim/dp/1590593561).